# How to show that two integrals are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

In my advanced calculus course, I am struggling with the following problem where we need to show that the two integrals are equal.

Consider a function $g:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$
defined by
$$
g(x,y) 
= 
\min \{x, y \} - xy,
\quad 
\mbox{for} 
\quad 
0 \le x, y \le 1.
$$

Now, for a continuous function
$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$,
then how do we prove that
\begin{align}
& {} 
\int_{0}^{1} 
\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\right)^{2}
\left[ 
\int_{x}^{1}
\int_{x}^{1}
f(y) (1-y) f(z) (1-z) \, dy \, dz
\right] \, dx \\[15pt]
& =
\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{0}^{1}
f(x) f(y) g(x,y) \, dy \, dx?
\end{align}

I am not even sure where to start and the most critical part for me is how do we convert the triple integration on the left to just double integration on the right. So, I would appreciate for any guidance. Thank you!

Update: Numerically I am able to verify. For example, considering $f(x) = 3x^{2}$, we get the following:
$$
LHS 
=
\frac{9}{112} 
=
RHS.
$$
But still do not know how we prove the general case!

Comment: @MartinR: I have updated the context!

Comment: What's does the $\wedge$ operator do in this context?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.: Edited $x \wedge y = \min \{x, y\}$.

Comment: For an idea about how to start, you can try writing $\iint f(x)f(y)g(x,y)\,dxdy = \iint_{x<y}+\iint_{y>x}$, so you can substitute what $g$ is in the different regions. There is a lot of symmetry, so you can see if you find patterns and simplify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be shown by simply changing order of integration.

The initial integral is the same as
$$
 \int_{0}^{1} 
\int_{x}^{1}
\int_{x}^{1}
f(y)f(z)
\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\right)^{2}(1-y) (1-z) \, dy \, dz
 \, dx 
$$

which is nothing else then:
$$
 \int_A
f(y)f(z)
\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\right)^{2} (1-y) (1-z) \, dy \, dz
 \, dx 
$$

with $A = \{0 \le x \le 1, x \le z \le 1, x \le y \le 1\}$
but we can rewrite $A$ as $$A = \{0 \le x \le \min\{y,z\}, 0 \le y \le 1, 0 \le z \le 1\}$$

And with that in mind we can rewrite our initial integral by changing orders of integration as

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min\{y,z\}}
f(y)f(z)
\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\right)^{2} (1-y) (1-z)  \, dx\, dy \, dz \\\\
=&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(y)f(z) (1-y)(1-z)\int_0^{\min\{y,z\}}
\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\right)^{2}  \, dx\, dy \, dz \\\\
=&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(y)f(z) (1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-\min\{y,z\}} - 1
\right)\, dy \, dz
\end{align}

But it holds (shown later): $$g(y,z) = (1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-\min\{y,z\}} - 1
\right)$$

So we get:
$$=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(y)f(z) g(y,z)\, dy \, dz$$

The result follows by simple renaming $z \to x$ and we are done.

Still to show that our claim holds, but that's an easy case split:

For $y\le z$ we have
\begin{align}
&(1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-\min\{y,z\}} - 1
\right) = (1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-y} - 1
\right) \\
=&(1-z)(1 - (1-y)) = (1-z)y = y - zy = g(y,z)
\end{align}

As well as for $z \le y$:
\begin{align}
&(1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-\min\{y,z\}} - 1
\right) = (1-y) (1-z)\left( 
\dfrac{1}{1-z} - 1
\right) \\
=&(1-y)(1 - (1-z)) = (1-y)z = z - zy = g(y,z)
\end{align}